# Getting data out of an array and writing it to a defined cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a loop running, and I am trying to combine the results in the array, match those results to a Defined Cell Name, and write another result within the same array to the same cell as the defined name. It is pull data from a tab delimited text file.

The array comes out like this

`"01/08/2019 18:00:00   BRANDED                 LOC     PN      THE PRODUCT NAME        +3.46       ThePrice"`

I need to concant LOC and PN in to the follow format "LOC_PN", find the Defined Cell with the "LOC_PN" name, and then write ThePrice to that cell on the ActiveSheet.

```
Public Sub ImportPrices_Click()
    ''Declare Variables
    Dim PathName As String
    Dim FileName As String        

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    PathName = "??????"        

    ''AP Prices
    FileName = PathName & "\" & "APPrices.txt"
    Set AP = fs.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)

    Dim arrAP()
    i = 0

    Do While Not AP.AtEndOfStream
        ReDim Preserve arrAP(i)
        arrBP(i) = AP.ReadLine
    Loop      

    ap.Close
End Sub
```

I appreciate your help ahead of time. I have been banging my head against my desk trying to figure out the writing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question and the Data layout of text file is not clear. from What I understood from the requirement of "match those results to a Defined Cell Name", I think storing each lines is to an array is not required at all. However in your code

1. I is not incremented
2. typo of arrBP instead of arrAP is found

Correcting the above may give you an array of each lines of the APPrices.txt for further processing.

However if Data layout of text file and your requirement as below 
[image]

then may try simple code like without array

```
 Option Base 0
 Public Sub ImportPrices_Click()
''Declare Variables
Dim PathName As String
Dim FileName As String

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
PathName = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
FileName = PathName & "\" & "APPrices.txt"
Set ap = fs.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)

Dim Cols As Variant, Ln As String, Price As String, LocPin As String
    Do While Not ap.AtEndOfStream
    Ln = ap.ReadLine
    Cols = Split(Ln, Chr(9))   ' each line is splited on tab ie Chr(9)
    Price = Cols(7)
    LocPin = Cols(3) & Cols(4)
    Debug.Print LocPin, Price
    'you may match the locPin here and put the price the cells
    Loop
ap.Close

End Sub
```

Or else another easy method (Modify to requirement)

```
Sub test2()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Rng As Range, C As Range, LastRow As Long
Workbooks.OpenText FileName:="C:\Users\user\Desktop\APPrices.txt", Origin:=437, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
        , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
        Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each Rng In wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(8).Cells
    Rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]&RC[-4]"      'Create column  9 With concanted LOc & Pin
    Next

    'Search Column 9 LOcPIN
    For Each Rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A25").Cells
    Set C = wb.ActiveSheet.Columns(9).Find(Rng.Value) ', LookIn:=xlValues) ', Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Offset(, 1).Value = C.Offset(, -1).Value                        ' Price
        End If
    Next Rng
wb.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: This was a huge help, thank you! I went with your first response.